# How to specify multiple classes that can match a given selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to practice DRY in my CSS (wink) and I'm stuck on how to solve this.

How do I reduce this:

```
table.shipmentItemList TD.title,
table.shipmentItemList TD.author,
table.shipmentItemList TD.options {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

To something like this:

```
table.shipmentItemList TD.title, TD.author, TD.options {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Or better yet this:

```
table.shipmentItemList TD .title, .author, .options {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: IF you're looking to do that kind of thing in CSS, you're going to have to look into LESS or SASS. As your code stands in standard CSS it's as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, you can only use SASS: http://sass-lang.com/

Standard CSS won't allow for the things you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), or [LESS PHP](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) if you'd rather do it on the server. What you're asking isn't possible with vanilla CSS.

Your example would look like this:

```
table.shipmentItemList {
    td {
        &.title, &.author, &.options {
            font-size: 1.0em;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at less.js it will let you do something like this:

```
table.shipmentItemList{
  TD.title, TD.author, TD.options {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
}
```